# JGit http clone repository but the repository can't pull

Tags: git, http, jgit

The clone code as flowing:

```
private static final String REMOTE_URL = "http://localhost:8088/git/5.git";
private static String login = "xxxx@gmail.com";
private static String password = "123456";

public static Repository cloneRepository() throws IOException, InvalidRemoteException, TransportException, GitAPIException {

    File localPath = new File("E:/temp/TestGitRepositorygithub");
    System.out.println(localPath);
    if (!localPath.exists() && !localPath.isDirectory()) {
        localPath.mkdir();
    }
    localPath.delete();

    // then clone .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/master"))
    System.out.println("Cloning from " + REMOTE_URL + " to " + localPath);
    CloneCommand clone = Git.cloneRepository().setURI(REMOTE_URL).setDirectory(localPath);
    if (REMOTE_URL.toString().contains("http") || REMOTE_URL.toString().contains("https")) {
        UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider user = new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(login, password);
        clone.setCredentialsProvider(user);
    }

    Git repo1 = clone.call();

    for (Ref b : repo1.branchList().setListMode(ListMode.ALL).call())
        System.out.println("(standard): cloned branch " + b.getName());
    repo1.close();
```

The pull code below

```
    File localPath = new File("E:/temp/TestGitRepositorygithub");
    FileRepositoryBuilder builder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    Repository repository = builder.setGitDir(new File(localPath + "/.git")).readEnvironment().findGitDir().build();

    Git git = new Git(repository);
    PullCommand pull = git.pull();
    PullResult call = pull.call();
```

will report the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException   
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.connect(TransportHttp.java:477)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportHttp.openFetch(TransportHttp.java:306)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1111)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:130)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:248)
```

If I change it like this

```
REMOTE_URL = "ssh://git@localhost:8999/5.git";
```

it will work well.

Comment: The stack trace points nowhere meaningful in the current JGit sources. Which version of JGit do you use? 
Apart from the NPE, the pull command won't work because the credentials provider isn't set.

Comment: the version of JGit which i use is 3.1.0.201310021548-r, and what does the credentials mean?

Comment: thanks , and should i set the credentials provider in the code? can you provide an example for me? thanks again.

Comment: use the credentials provider just as you did in the CloneCommand:     `pull.setCredentialsProvider( ... );`